Can I train a logistic regression model for combining ML models to form an ensemble?
I have 3 ML models trained to perform classification on a dataset. I want to combine them into an ensemble model. I understand that there are multiple ways to do this - voting classifier, stacking, bagging, boosting etc.
But I want to combine the probabilities instead of classes, which is possible through a weighted sum I think. To assign the weights to the probabilities from each model, instead of trying multiple combinations of weights, I got a suggestion to use logistic regression with the probability values as features. Is this an accepted approach to getting the weights or coefficients for probability values from each of my models?
